# Apple WebKit deprecated?

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

The code is not working even if I ignore the import WebKit. Getting deprecated WebKit error. I was trying to copy code examples from Apple developer docs website.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate{ // getting error not declared
    
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView! // WKWebView Deprecated
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            
        let myURL = URL(string:"http://172.20.10.3:5501")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(myRequest)
    }

}
```

The above code is not working even if I ignored the import WebKit.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZghv.png)

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using. Your code doesn't give me those errors when pasted into an Xcode 11.0 playground.

Comment: I am using Xcode 10.3

Comment: Try restarting Xcode. And you should be using Xcode 11 - always best to be current.

Comment: Yes I updated to Xcode 11 and even created new project still it’s giving me same error.

Comment: Hey I have added the error photo

Comment: Please read the errors, especially the import line. None of the errors say anything about WebKit being deprecated. It seems you named your project WebKit. Don't name your project after a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the name of your project? Looks like you might have named your project WebKit, and that would give you the error you posted.  Rename project or create a new one with a different name and the error will go away.

See screenshot.
[image]